# LinkedBlockingQueue - java - queue full

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a linked blocking queue around which I coordinate
the work of 20 consumer threads and 20 producer threads.
The capacity is 10 of the queue (I am just testing currently).

But instead of blocking, when I put into a full queue,
I get this error below. Why so? The JavaDoc says
the queue should be blocking in this case.
Am I misunderstanding something?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.addAll(AbstractQueue.java:187)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put-E-) on the `LinkedBlockingQueue`. `put` will wait as long as necessary until space is available. `offer` will return a boolean indicating success or failure.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see my mistake now.